# Schengen visa to vist Italy with my husband who is from South Africa

Tags: south-african-citizens, spouses

I have dual citizenship South African and Italian.

My South African husband and I are planning to go to Italy in May 2017 for a visit.

We have already been on a two-week visit in October 2010 but were not married at the time and my brother in Italy sent an invitation letter.

Now that we are officially married, does the same invitation process applies or he can travel with a spouse visa?

Is a visa easier to obtain this time around as he has already obtained one Schengen Vvsa previously?

Comment: You've asked almost the same question an hour ago; please clarify how this question might be different.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate long term immigration question better suited to expatriates I believe.

Comment: I am sorry to seem deceiveing but since the emigration angle of my wife is only for the reason to cash the RA Policy and we will be returning to SA eventually as we have family ties here I would not really consider mine a permanent emigration and my wife still has SA citizenship so after a few months we will come back eventually. This is the reason why I reposted the question under a different guise

Comment: Let me suggest that you delete this one. You have included lots of good information in your first question and, hopefully, you'll get the advice that you need. Posting additional questions doesn't help, nor does offering different versions.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your input let me try and delete this post: please I do I do it?

Comment: Wait, what -- yesterday you wanted to go with a _wife_. Did he/she have an overnight gender transition?

Comment: ah ah ah funny no is the wife posting now but using my husband's profile